# PG::ConnectionBad with rails and pgbouncer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pgbouncer

I have rails and pgBouncer, and I have `reconnect: true` in the `database.yml` but I keep getting this in the console:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() server closed the connection unexpectedly
```

The same error happens in sidekiq but not in web, shouldn't rails reconnect after having this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a timeout configured in the server (that I wasn't aware of). So it doesn't have anything to do with rails/pgbouncer, in fact `reconnect` flag in the `database.yml` isn't used anymore in rails.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a solution to set the below configuration parameters of Postgresql.

**tcp_keepalives_idle (integer)**

Specifies the number of seconds of inactivity after which TCP should send a keepalive message to the client. A value of 0 uses the system default. This parameter is supported only on systems that support TCP_KEEPIDLE or an equivalent socket option, and on Windows; on other systems, it must be zero. In sessions connected via a Unix-domain socket, this parameter is ignored and always reads as zero.

**tcp_keepalives_interval (integer)**

Specifies the number of seconds after which a TCP keepalive message that is not acknowledged by the client should be retransmitted. A value of 0 uses the system default. This parameter is supported only on systems that support TCP_KEEPINTVL or an equivalent socket option, and on Windows; on other systems, it must be zero. In sessions connected via a Unix-domain socket, this parameter is ignored and always reads as zero.

**tcp_keepalives_count (integer)**

Specifies the number of TCP keepalives that can be lost before the server's connection to the client is considered dead. A value of 0 uses the system default. This parameter is supported only on systems that support TCP_KEEPCNT or an equivalent socket option; on other systems, it must be zero. In sessions connected via a Unix-domain socket, this parameter is ignored and always reads as zero.